Problems while trying to debug WPF application with VS2022
I have a WPF application to change targeting .NET framework 4.6.2 that calls an API backend. If there is much change to display, the UI hangs for a while. But after the update is completed it is still not responsive right away. It has quite a complicated multilevel grid on the window. It is sluggish when used, but can be dealt with.
I have a hard time debugging however. Almost always I get this message in VS (Version 17.11.0 Preview 7.0):

It even happens when I start the app and only attach the debugger to it afterward. Is there a way to overcome this?
